# 420YpCbCr8 to RGB conversation

Tags: video, ios7, opengl-es-2.0, rgb, fragment-shader

I try to set texture with `CVPixelBuffer` that i get from video stream

```
NSDictionary* videoOutputOptions = @{ (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange] };
        self.videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:videoOutputOptions];
```

to texture that i want to use. For this purpose I use next fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec2 v_texCoord;
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D SamplerUV;
uniform sampler2D SamplerY;
uniform mat3 colorConversionMatrix;

void main()
{
    mediump vec3 yuv;
    lowp vec3 rgb;

    // Subtract constants to map the video range start at 0
    yuv.x = (texture2D(SamplerY, v_texCoord).r - (16.0/255.0));
    yuv.yz = (texture2D(SamplerUV, v_texCoord).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5));

    rgb = colorConversionMatrix * yuv;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb,1);
}
```

And conversation matrix is

```
// BT.709, which is the standard for HDTV.
static const GLfloat kColorConversion709[] = {
    1.164,  1.164, 1.164,
    0.0, -0.213, 2.112,
    1.793, -0.533,   0.0,
};
```

But as result i got `greened` texture - think this mean that I use incorrect conversation.
My result:

[image: greened image]

So, also try to change konversation matrix to another one - [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/Mac/GPUImageAVCamera.m).
Also try variants from [this](http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html) resource. But lookl like maybe it's problem not only in conversation, but in fragment shader also?

Any suggestion, why i got greened image? (**question**).

**EDIT**

This is mathod how I get textures (use apple sample `AVBasicVideoOutput` and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage))

```
- (void)displayPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer frameSize:(CGSize)presentationSize
{
    CVReturn err;
    if (pixelBuffer != NULL) {
        int frameWidth = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
        int frameHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

        if (!_videoTextureCache) {
            NSLog(@"No video texture cache");
            return;
        }
        [self cleanUpTextures];
        //Use the color attachment of the pixel buffer to determine the appropriate color conversion matrix.
        CFTypeRef colorAttachments = CVBufferGetAttachment(pixelBuffer, kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrixKey, NULL);

        if (colorAttachments == kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4) {
            _preferredConversion = kColorConversion601;
        }
        else {
            _preferredConversion = kColorConversion709;
        }
         //CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage will create GLES texture optimally from CVPixelBufferRef.
         //Create Y and UV textures from the pixel buffer. These textures will be drawn on the frame buffer Y-plane.
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _videoTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL,  GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth, frameHeight, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &_lumaTexture);
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
        }

        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_lumaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_lumaTexture));
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // UV-plane.
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _videoTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 1, &_chromaTexture);
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage %d", err);
        }

        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_chromaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_chromaTexture));
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _vertexBufferID);

        CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If someone put `-1` - please add comment why u do this and whats wrong - maybe for someone problem is visible and simple, but for others - not

Comment: Note that in the above code, there is a problem with comparing the string colorAttachments to the constant kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4. The proper way to do that is to use the test (CFStringCompare(colorAttachments, kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally - i found my mistake - stupid typo:

Instead `SamplerUV` i use `SamplerUY` in code when assigning uniform - change it - and all works perfectly!.

Also use next conversation matrix

```
    1.1643,  0.0000,  1.2802,
    1.1643, -0.2148, -0.3806,
    1.1643,  2.1280,  0.0000
```

So if u have incorrect image - check each component - chroma and luma - one of it incorrect.

Maybe for someone this info will be useful